# App Store asks me Apple ID password with an incorrect email

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios, apple-id

I have an iPhone 4S from about 2 years. Till now the App Store never asked me a password different from the one I've set when create the Apple account. Today, for no apparent reason, it asked me a different email while I was trying to update my apps. I don't know this email and I think that I've never typed it, neither set it as my default email. If I go to iTunes it shows clearly that my Apple ID has the correct email, I also tried to verify it and the password is correct. But the App Store keeps asking the password for that different account, and there I can't change it. How do I "say to the App Store" that I want to sign it with a different email?

**Edit**

I recognized that I haven't problems updating other apps, just one: whatsapp. I imported this app from another computer, may this be the problem?

Comment: Is it jailbroken? Do you have any apps installed from different sources than App Store?

Comment: @iskra Now I recognized that I have problems updating just one, which I imported from another computer. Maybe I cannot update it because it has been purchased with another account?

Comment: Maybe that copy of Whatsapp is registered to that other guy's AppleID.  ... just a conjecture.  Maybe this is how they get each guy to download his own copy of the program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that **ALL** the apps are downloaded/purchased from your account. If not, only *your* apps will update.

If you want to change account go to settings->iTunes & App Store->Apple ID->Sign out->and enter your other account.